# Is there a term that's used to refer to an idea that opens the door to whole new ideas?

Tags: word-request

I can think of "revolutionary theories" such as "quantum physics", but a theory is too specific and I want to be more general. However, if I use the phrase "revolutionary idea", it's too general, and doesn't mean idea that opens the door to whole new ideas. Is there any such word or phrase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say ***groundbreaking ideas***.

Or ***[seminal](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/seminal)*** *ideas* (usually used for work of a scientist that opened up a field).

***Trailblazing*** would also work.

I think ***breakthrough*** could also be used to refer to such ideas.

***Watershed moment*** in its figurative sense is also possible. It's a critical turning point in time where everything changes that will never be the same as before. This meaning comes from the literal meaning of a point or division in a river or a stream where the river is split into two or more paths.

---

Also try *Rosetta stone*.

> The term ***Rosetta stone*** has been also used idiomatically to represent a crucial key in the process of decryption of encoded information, especially when a small but representative sample is recognised as the clue to understanding a larger whole.